# how could i validate 3 fields with jquery.validate or itegrated with asp.net mvc 3  DataAnnotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, validation

i have 3 textbox for a valid phone : phone_part1 ,phone_part2,phone_part3 , how can i use

jquery.validate to validate 3 as a valid phone_number:

phone_part1: 3 number
phone_part2: 4 number
phone_part3: 4 number

they both required , and if one of them is not valid , then output one validation message :

please input a valid phone number.

i'm not familiar with jquery.validate , thanks for any help !!

and if you can do this use mvc data anotation attribute with client validation , that's

pretty pretty good !!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can put one Textbox and validate it with Regular Expression

in Model:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{3}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

if you want to use 3 textbox":

```
public class Contact
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{3}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    public string Phone_Part1 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    public string Phone_Part2 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{3}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone")]
    public string Phone_Part3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks , Morteza ,   if one/two/three of 3 textbox is not valid , then output ONLY one validation message ? how can i achieve this ?

Comment: it is better you use one text box. but if you use 3 text box they had 3 validation message. if you want one validation message you can hide other with jquery.